# Spring Integration - Missing Messages

Tags: spring-integration

I have an integration application that mostly works, but noticed yesterday a message was lost.  At the time, the service-activator endpoint was extremely busy processing a previous message.

Basically, my integration flow is:
jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter --> splitter -> aggregator (based on a type field) -> [pollable channel] --> service-activator

From the log, I can see a group of messages polled, split, aggregated, expired (via a message store reaper), and placed on the creation channel.  There is a preSend and postSend event in the log for placing the message on the creationChannel, but that's the end of it.  It never gets to my service-activator, there's no messages in the jdbc message store and I dont see any errors.

Could there an issue with how I have either the service-activator or poller configured (or a combination)?

Here is the configuration applicable to the issue.

```
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="1000" receive-timeout="0" />    
<int-jdbc:message-store id="jdbc-messageStore" data-source="dataSource"  /> 

<int:channel id="creationChannel" >
   <int:queue  message-store="jdbc-messageStore" />
</int:channel>               

<!-- Endpoint responsible for creating Archive from List of Document objects -->
<bean id="archiveCreator" class="org.abc.ArchiveCreator"/>

<int:service-activator ref="archiveCreator" method="createArchive" input-channel="creationChannel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should mark your `<poller>` as `<transactional>`.

Another point switch on the `org.springframework.integration` DEBUG logging level and show here the log, when a message is lost.

Comment: Thanks Artem.  I do have DEBUG on was able to follow the flow from Polling, through the postSend on the archive channel, but that's where it ends.  As far as transactional, I will implement that, but from a implementation perspective, do you see any other flaws with my configuration?  In otherwords, are there any polling settings that would case messages to expire if they were not consumed in a certain amount of time, or are there any considerations I should be aware of when using service-activator with a pollable channel?